# XCode - Making ordered names imageView array?

Tags: ios, xcode

I made a array of type UIImageView, and a button that add new imageview to the array
i want to name each new image with the order image1, image2, image3 .. etc

```
var array = [UIImageView]()

@IBAction func addImage(_ sender: Any)
let newImage = UIImageView()
self.view.addSubView(newImage)
array.append(newImage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using name you can work with tag

```
newImage.tag = array.count

array.append(newImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use tags for that.
Naming the variable dynamically isn't possible.

```
imageView.tag = X
```